# Como mover uma div com o mouse JQUERY?

Tags: jquery

Bom dia , eu queria  algum plugin para eu mover redimensionar a div e tals, isso tudo com o mouse, é possível existe? eu procurei e nao achei nenhum plugin , se alguem conhecer, por favor informar obrigada.

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/266755/8063

Answer (score 1):

A biblioteca JQuery UI tem funções mover e redimensionar. Para ela é necessário primeiro incluir o JQuery normal.

### Mover

Para mover um `div` ou qualquer outro elemento html precisa de utilizar a função `draggable` sobre o seletor desse elemento

```js
$(function() {
    $("#meudiv").draggable();
});
```

```css
#meudiv {
  background-color:lightGreen;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
<div id="meudiv" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Clique e arraste para mover</p>
</div>
```

### Redimensionar

Para redimensionar a função a utilizar é `resizable`.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#meudiv").resizable();
});
```

```css
#meudiv {
  background-color:lightGreen;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  
<div id="meudiv" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Redimensione este div</p>
</div>
```

Neste ultimo exemplo foi necessário incluir o CSS base do JQuery UI para ter a seta no canto inferior direito que permite redimensionar.

Estes exemplos partiram dos exemplos na [documentação oficial do JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)

- [JQuery UI Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/)
- [JQuery UI Resizable](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/)

Eles tem ainda mais algumas ações tal como `droppable` ou `selectable` que lhe podem interessar.