# Ajuda com slide ranger do jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slide

Tenho um slider ranger do jQuery ui ele funciona normal mas o problema e que quando estou no mobile(pelo celular) eu não consigo arrastar o slide para que ele funcione tem que clicar em cima.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#hora-range").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 1440,
        step: 15,
        slide: function(e, ui) {
            $(".min-hora-label").html('HORA MIN= ' + ui.values[0]);
            $(".max-hora-label").html('HORA MAX= ' + ui.values[1]);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>

<div id="hora-range"></div>
<div class="min-hora-label"></div>
<div class="max-hora-label"></div>
```

O código está também no [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vhtnep50/1/).

Pesquisei no Google e achei o jQuery Touch Punch que prometia resolver o problema mas não consegui. Alguém sabe o que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Tentou com "touch-action: pan-x" ?

Comment: @hugocsl onde coloco ele?

Comment: Não sei se resolve, sugeri para vc fazer um teste. Coloque no **.css** tipo `#slider { touch-action: pan-x; }` aqui vc pode ler mais https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action

Comment: O punch funciona perfeitamente, talvez vc implementou errado. Dá uma olhada [neste link](http://dvdteste.hospedagemdesites.ws/punch.php), teste e veja o código fonte para ver como é a estrutura.

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/266755/8063